# Volume of a pyramid

Tags: calculus

Let a pyramid has a triangular basis with vertices $A(2, 0, 0), \; B (0, 3, 0)$ and $C(0, 0, 6)$ and let its top be $D(2, 3,8)$. Find the volume of the pyramid.

*I did the following:*

I computed the area of the basis. 
$$\left ( ABC \right )= \frac{1}{2}\left | \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
 -2& 3 & 0\\ 
 -2& 0 &6 
\end{vmatrix} \right |=18$$

Then I integrated from $0$ to $6$ and got that the volume is $108$.

However, evaluating the volume using a double integral I do not get the same result. Using a double integral I did the following:

$$\iint \limits_{D} f(x, y)\, {\rm d}y\, {\rm d} x =\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{3-3x/2}\left ( 6-3x-2y\right )\, {\rm d}y \, {\rm d}x =6$$

whereas $f(x, y)$ is the plane containing $A, B, C$. Where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Instead of using a $3\times 3$ determinant to find the area of a triangle (the base), maybe you could use the similar formula with a $4\times 4$ determinant to get the volume of the tetrahedron (pyramid) directly?

Comment: Hmm , I am not aware of something like that. Could you provide a formula?

Comment: Basically, the correct result accroding to this link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59284/volume-of-a-pyramid-using-an-integral is $6$ which is exactly what I got using the double integral.

Comment: In the first approach, do you multiply the area of the base by the height? Because that gives the area of a *prism* by the height. The volume of a *pyramid* has a factor $1/3$ in front. Regarding a $4\times 4$ determinant formula, google led me to [http://www.had2know.com/academics/tetrahedron-volume-4-vertices.html](http://www.had2know.com/academics/tetrahedron-volume-4-vertices.html).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Hmm I just checked your online calculator and it gives me a result of $14$. What is going on here? According to the link I gave the result is $6$ without the use of double integral. I'm lost.

Comment: Neither of your end results is correct. In the last approach, maybe are you calculating the volume of the pyramid $ABCO$ instead of $ABCD$? The former is one sixth of the volume $2\cdot 3\cdot 6$ of the corresponding rectangular box with edges parallel to the coordinate axes. My link has a "machine" where you can type in your four points and get the result. Have you determined the distance between the point $D$ and the plane containing $A$, $B$ and $C$?

Comment: Actually I am computing the other pyramid... you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Tetrahedron: Volume](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Volume). We are told that

> For a tetrahedron with vertices $~A=\big(a_1,~a_2,~a_3\big),\quad B=\big(b_1,~b_2,~b_3\big),\quad C=\big(c_1,~c_2,~c_3\big)$, 
>  and $~D=\big(d_1,~d_2,~d_3\big),~$ the volume is $V=\dfrac{\Big|\det~\big(A-D,~B-D,~C-D\big)\Big|}6~,~$ or any other 
>  combination of pairs of vertices that form a simply connected graph.